# NFA where there are two 0s separated by a multiple of 4

Tags: formal-languages, automata

I've been following Automata and Formal Languages in my college and I came across
this particular exercise.
While the solution presented seems correct, I take on Automata Tutor trying this exercise a 0 out of 10. I can't understand what was wrong here cause overall it seems correct. Thanks a lot if you can help me.

[image]

Comment: The feedback at the bottom of the image you posted gives you a coutnerexample. With input 000000 your NFA will be in the state $\{1,2,4,5,12\}$, which does not include a final state. In particular, notice that if the input word does not contain a "1", then your NFA cannot possibly accept.

Comment: Just to clarify, the language accepted by the NFA must contain two 0 separated by a string whose length is a multiple of 4?

Comment: Probably the multiple needs to be positive, otherwise $0$ is a multiple of $4$ and it suffices to check whether the input word contains a $0$.

Comment: Needs to be positive, I confirm this. Thanks Steven for the observations. Still trying to figure this out, might update in  case I find something useful

Comment: In that case the feedback at the bottom is a typo? That one contains five 0 only

Comment: @Russel I don't know honestly, I think it's a typo too

Comment: My guess is that the input word needs to contain two $0$s at some positions $i,j$ with $j>i$ and $j-i \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$. In the feedback $i=1$ and $j=5$.

Comment: The edge from 2 to 3, shouldn't that be labelled with 0 instead of 1?

Comment: @grovesti can you give the description of the language of the NFA the way it is specified in Automata Tutor?

Comment: @HendrikJan making the edge as you said makes Automata say:
Your NFA does not accept the string '01010' while the correct solution does.

Comment: @Russel the description of the language is:
Construct an NFA that recognizes the following language of strings over the alphabet {0,1}:there are two zeroes separated from a number of positions multiple of 4. Note: 0 is a multiple of 4

Comment: @grovesti Perhaps I misunderstand: we want two 0's with a multiple of 4 letters in between? However '01010' does not satisfy that requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a logic contradiction in the exercise; I tried both combinations but nothing seems to work. Tried the logic as Russel said, having a loop composed in this way. Also tried Steven reasoning, given the thought behind that. Seems like the automata at least in Automata Tutor has to begin with both 0 and 1, having a loop composed of 0/1, given the hints the exercise gives, then ending with a 1. The moment you put 0 as the second state goes into the loop and asks for the correct string to be 00000. Then one puts final state the fifth zero and the exercise combines other requests. Upon satisfying them all, I conclude that simply, the exercise itself is not totally correct behind, trying both of the logics linked here.
Given this kind of exercise, which you can also find online in other places are implemented as I've shown before or in one other way, a little different but still, doesn't work on Automata Tutor. It's wrong on how the question is posed, I'll tell the teacher on that.

As also Hendrik noted, it's contradicting in the requests, cause one misinterpretes the other ones and it's all conflicting upon itself.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is just me, but I think that the description of the language from the Automata Tutor is ambiguous. In my understanding, the description is for the language containing all string $w$ such that there exists two 0 in $w$ at positions $i$ and $j$ such that $i$ and $j$ are multiples of 4. I assume that the position of the symbols begins at 0. However, Steven's interpretation (from the comment above) that the language is the set of string that contains two 0 at positions $i$ and $j$ such that $j-i$ is a multiple of 4, also fits the description. It doesn't help that the two sample strings $00000$ and $01010$ works for both interpretations.

One way for us to know is for you to try to create an NFA for the two interpretations and see which one works. Here, I will only describe the NFA for my case and will let you or Steven to fill for the other one (although my construction can easily be modified to implement the other interpretation).

The idea is, the NFA at the beginning is allowed to consume a number of symbols whose total length is a multiple of 4. Think of this as the phase where the NFA guesses position $i$, the position of the first 0. Note that I said *allowed to consume* and *not required to consume* at the start since it is possible for $i$ to be 0, the start position in the string. You can implement this by having a loop composed of 4 states (including the start state) that may consume 4 symbols per loop. The start state is the beginning ang the ending state in this loop. When the NFA decides to exit/skip the loop, it means that it found $i$. So it will move from the start state to an intermediate state $q_i$ while consuming a 0.

The next phase is to guess position $j$. At state $q_i$, the NFA can consume 4 symbols at a time again in a loop (same as above, but the beginning and ending state of the loop is now $q_i$). Otherwise, the NFA can guess to exit/skip this loop and read four symbols, with the last symbol being 0, and enter the accept state, which signifies that it found $j$ already.

Finally, at the accept state, the NFA will consume all remaining symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Interpretation difficulties with *two 0s separated by a multiple of 4* aside, the depicted automaton makes a `1` a requirement.
Approach it from the end:
A `0` after the appropriate distance should take you to an accepting state. No further symbols should lead to a non-accepting state.
Before that `0`, there are three (judging by the example from the feedback. Or four, if I was to interpret *separated by a multiple of 4*) symbols which may or may not be `0`.
And another mandatory `0`.
Symbols preceding that don't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The transition from state 2 to state 3 should be 0